# Why when setting the state in React doesn't give the right value all the time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

So, I am making a todolist app and I have this code:

```
./components/Overlay.js
import { useState } from "react";

function Overlay({Task, SetTask}) {
    const [priority, setPriority] = useState('');
    const [text, setText] = useState('');
    return ( 
        <div className="bg-[#040e16] p-10 rounded-3xl">
            <input type="text" className="bg-[#0d1821] mr-3 w-[30rem] h-10 text-lg rounded-lg p-2" value={text} onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}/>
            <button className="bg-[#0d1821] p-2 w-16 rounded-lg hover:bg-[#3b42a4] transition-all" onClick={() => {SetTask({
                text: text,
                priority: priority
            });
            console.log(Task)}}>Add</button><br />
            <p>Priority: {priority}</p> <br />
            <button onClick={() => setPriority('high')}><img src="/hi-priority.png" alt="" className="w-12 hover:bg-[#3b42a4] mr-5 transition-all rounded-2xl"/></button>
            <button onClick={() => setPriority('medium')}><img src="/md-priority.png" alt="" className="w-12 hover:bg-[#3b42a4] mr-5 transition-all rounded-2xl"/></button>
            <button onClick={() => setPriority('low')}><img src="/lo-priority.png" alt="" className="w-12 hover:bg-[#3b42a4] mr-5 transition-all rounded-2xl"/></button>
        </div>
     );
}

export default Overlay;
```

```
import { useState } from "react";
import NavBar from "../../components/NavBar";
import Overlay from "../../components/Overlay";
function Dashboard() {
    const [on, setOn] = useState(false);
    const [task, setTask] = useState({
        text: "",
        priority: "",
    })
    
    return ( 
        <div className="">
            <NavBar
            onClick={() =>{
                setOn(!on);
            }}
            />
            <div className="p-5">
                {on ? <Overlay Task={task} SetTask={setTask} /> : <span></span>}
            </div>
            

        </div>
     );
};
export default Dashboard;
```

When I `console.log(task);`
I use the useState with a setter function (as normal) but when updating it (when you click add) I have a delay like shown in the picture but the second time it just works, I am sure there is some problem in my code can anybody help me with it.
I don't always get the right output, it is delayed for example like this:
[image: when clicking the add button]

Comment: If you want to check for an updated state in React you should use `useEffect`: `useEffect(() => { console.log(Task); }, [Task]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually how React works, state on React updates Asynchronously, meaning that the state will not update instantly, but instead, it will trigger a rerender and then show the new updated state, this is also mentioned in their [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

There are various techniques you can use for your case, you can check if your priority has a value before rendering the priority data for example:

```js
./components/Overlay.js
import { useState } from "react";

function Overlay({Task, SetTask}) {
    const [priority, setPriority] = useState('');
    const [text, setText] = useState('');
    return ( 
        <div className="bg-[#040e16] p-10 rounded-3xl">
            <input type="text" className="bg-[#0d1821] mr-3 w-[30rem] h-10 text-lg rounded-lg p-2" value={text} onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}/>
            <button className="bg-[#0d1821] p-2 w-16 rounded-lg hover:bg-[#3b42a4] transition-all" onClick={() => {SetTask({
                text: text,
                priority: priority
            });
            console.log(Task)}}>Add</button><br />
            {priority && <>
               <p>Priority: {priority}</p> <br />
            <button onClick={() => setPriority('high')}><img src="/hi-priority.png" alt="" className="w-12 hover:bg-[#3b42a4] mr-5 transition-all rounded-2xl"/></button>
            <button onClick={() => setPriority('medium')}><img src="/md-priority.png" alt="" className="w-12 hover:bg-[#3b42a4] mr-5 transition-all rounded-2xl"/></button>
            <button onClick={() => setPriority('low')}><img src="/lo-priority.png" alt="" className="w-12 hover:bg-[#3b42a4] mr-5 transition-all rounded-2xl"/></button>
            </> }
           
        </div>
     );
}

export default Overlay;
```

You can also use useEffect to listen to state updates.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(`priority state changed to ${priority}`);
}, [priority]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `onClick` the `SetTask` executes but as we all know state setters are cached for efficiency, the console.log is executed first before setting the `Task` object. Once the `task` object is set, the component is then re-rendered and you see the correct value the next time.